# MySQL primary key

Tags: mysql

```
   CREATE TABLE branch_book_list (
       branch_name CHAR(10),
       book_ISBN CHAR (13),
       book_name CHAR(40),
       PRIMARY KEY (branch_name, book_ISBN)
   )
```

A few blogs say there can be only one primary key in a relation but when I execute this MySQL creates the table.

Comment: You only have one primary key in there... so I don't really see what your question is about.

Comment: That is one primary key, it just happens to have two columns.

Comment: @vini [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/687834) is not a very good suggested edit. [Code formatting should be used for code only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single primary key can contain multiple columns. It's still one key then.

It's a good practise though, to make the primary key a single column numeric/autonum value, also called a *surrogate key*. For the actual unique combination of Branch_name and ISBN, you can suffice with a *unique index*.

Comment: Also check the addition. Not an answer, but a good adice, I think.

Comment: Say i've a data as x y in one row x z in another row ,it is inserting but both riws should have a unique values right.i mean those both columns are primary key.

Comment: You can have only one primary key, but that doesn't mean you cannot make other columns (or combinations of columns) unique. You do that by adding a unique constraint (usually by adding a unique index) to the column or columns.

Comment: If you specify two columns, then the *combination of those two* must be unique. The individual columns can still have duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single compound Primary key on your version, there are those who would tell you to avoid that, but your real problem is normalisation.

For instance in your design, each branch can only have one copy of a book.
Book name will be duplicated.
There's nowhere sensible in there for branch address, book author etc...

Normalise your table

It should be Books with a unique key of ISBN ( you could make it primary as well, but that can cause problems)

Branches with some identifier e.g BranchID

Stock
BookID, BranchID, Qty?

If this is a library then often each copy of a book has a registration number, so you could invert a few things

and go 
Stocks keyed by registration number, with a BranchID, and a BookId (ISBN) and get rid of the compound key.

The key point to take away from this is to imagine you were doing all this on paper, would you be happy with going through your entire stock list for every branch, to rename a book, or to add the author to each one. Probably not eh? Writing the code to do something as inefficient as that is less work, but no more fun.